# Making 1 message handler return the same function to every input

Tags: python, bots, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make 1 message handler return one same function to every input it gets.

For example, instead of making these 2 message handler return the same function 'editing' when the input is equal to 'Edit' or 'ADD':

```
messageHandler(
                    Filters.regex('^(Edit)$'), editing),
messageHandler(
                    Filters.regex('^(ADD)$'), editing)
```

I wanted to add something like :

```
 messageHandler(
                        Filters.regex('^(%s)$' %(user_input)), editing)
```

So everything its typed returns the same function 'editing'

For a more specific case, if necessary, consider this [code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py) . If, for some reason, I wanted to add only 1 message handler which returns the function 'start' to everything the user types. How could it be done?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like callbacks ?

Comment: you might be looking for string formatting, so you can loop over your collection of substrings to create each regex .. however, adding some examples of your input would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered at the [Github discussions](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/2735) of `python-telegram-bot` where it was pointed out that one can use [`Filters.text`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/v13.7/telegram.ext.filters.html#id6) to filter for all incoming text messages. Alternatively, [`Filters.all`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/v13.7/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.all) would even accept all non-text messages.